# Adding three cells if a cell has a value, and if it doesn't, adding two

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

So basically here's what I want to do:

I need to add cells B12 and C12 normally, however -

If cell C3 has a certain text value (let's say "Apples"), I need to add B12, C12, and K3.

But if C3 -isn't- Apples, it should just add B12 and C12.

Additionally, I have two versions of Apples: "Apples - Red" and "Apples - Green". Maybe an *Apples* wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try simple:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C3, "Apples*"), SUM(B12:C12, K3), SUM(B12:C12))
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(C3, "Apples"), SUM(B12:C12, K3), SUM(B12:C12))
```

[image: 0]

---

if your "Apples" are numbers you can do:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C3&"", "123*"), SUM(B12:C12, K3), SUM(B12:C12))
```

or:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(C3&"", "123"), SUM(B12:C12, K3), SUM(B12:C12))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

`=if(REGEXMATCH(C3, "(?i).*apples.*"), SUM(B12,C12,K3), SUM(B12,C12))`

`(?i).*apples.*` is [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches any string that contains the words apples, ignoring case. So it will match any of the following cell contents: `Apples - Red`, `AWFEFAPPLESWEFWE`, `apples`, `apples - purple`, `red aPPLES`, etc. You can narrow the regex a bit if you want to be more strict.

Breaking it down, the regex is built as follows:

- `(?i)` - Ignore case for the entire matching pattern
- `.` - Matches any character.
- `*` - repeats that match 0 or more times.
- `apples` - indicates that we have to match appples
- `.*` - Like above, matches any string, including a zero-length string.

So it translates to "Ignoring case, match any string that has apples in it."

`REGEXMATCH()` is a google spreadsheet function that lets us compare a cell's contents against a regular expression.

The rest of it is just a standard `if`.